# How to limit responsive ad size

Tags: javascript, html, css

My responsive ads are running good on desktop but on mobile it shows huge block.
I want to limit my ad size on mobile device to '320*50'
But i don't know how to edit code.

here is my responsive ad code
`<div data-ad="mywebsite_responsive_horizontal_one" data-devices="m:1,t:1,d:1" class="demand-supply"></div>`

Comment: Well, if you don't know how to edit code then we are kinda limited on how we could possibly help. But, if you are willing to learn and want to solve this issue, then you would want to start looking at CSS. The CSS is what alters the width/height etc. So start looking at the `demand-supply` class within the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the div contains your ad, and the ad does not override the width and size, add a style attribute:

```
<div data-ad="mywebsite_responsive_horizontal_one" data-devices="m:1,t:1,d:1" class="demand-supply" style="width: 320px; height:50px"></div>
```

Or create a css class in the css file, then add it:

css:

```
.smaller-ad { width: 320px; height:50px }
```

HTML:

```
<div data-ad="mywebsite_responsive_horizontal_one" data-devices="m:1,t:1,d:1" class="demand-supply smaller-ad"></div>
```

**Edit**: if sometimes the add is actually smaller, you may want to use max-height and max-width instead